# sencha web start fails exception osx

Tags: macos, exception, extjs, web

I've installed sencha cmd on mac os x 10.7.5. When I try to start the web server with the command: **"sencha web start"** I receive the following error message:

[...]

```
14:28:03.274 [main] ERROR com.sencha.command.Sencha - org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
     at com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException.wrap(BasicException.java:51)
     at com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException.stealthify(BasicException.java:43)
     at com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException.raise(BasicException.java:35)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:64)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:80)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:148)
```

[...]

Is anyone has some idea what can be wrong ? I've tried both sencha cmd versions 5.0.0 and 4.0.4...and the error message is always the same. I'm absolutely beginner in sencha so maybe Im doing something completely wrong

Comment: What version of Java do you have?

Comment: java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)